# (Kinect v2) Alternative Kinect Fusion Pipeline (texture mapping)

Tags: c++, textures, kinect, fusion

I am trying a different Pipeline without success until now.

The Idea is to use the classic pipeline (as in the Explorer Example) but additionally to use the last ColorImage for the texutre.

So the idea (after clicking SAVE MESH):

1. Save current Image as BMP
2. Get the current transformation [m_pVolume->GetCurrentWorldToCameraTransform(&m_worldToCameraTransform);] .. lets call it M
3. Transform all Mesh vertices v in the last Camera Space Coordinate System ( M * v )
4. Now the current m_pMapper refers to the latest Frame which we want to use [ m_pMapper->MapCameraPointToColorSpace(camPoint, &colorPoint);  ]

In theory I should have now every Point of the fusion mesh as a texture coordinate.. I want to use them to export as OBJ File (with texture and not only color).

What am I doing wrong?

The 3D Transformations seem to be correct.. when I visualize the resulting OBJ file in MeshLab I can see that the transformation is correct.. the WorldCoordinateSystem is Equal to the latest recorded position.

Only the texture is not set correctly.

I would be very very very very happy if anyone could help me. I am trying already for a long time :/

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Exactly, what do you get? A well scanned 3D object with a wrong texture applied to it?

Comment: Yes correct :/ 
If you want - I can send you the complete code (if you want to try it yourself).

Comment: If you send me a Kinect too! ;) I used to work with it at a former job. Btw, I can't see nothing wrong in your pipeline. I can think of some possible error though: is M really what you expect it to be? is v actually in World coords? If answers to these questions are both "yes", then the issue must be in point 4. But there I can't help you, cause I've never seen Microsoft implementation of Kinect Fusion (I worked with PCL KinFu)

Comment: How can I send you a mail?

Comment: It seems that M and v are correct.. because the result looks to be transformed correctly into the last recorded frame..only the texture coordinates are buggy :/